# Angular 7, почему прокрутку на странице при исползиваные mat-checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

Я уже несколько дней не могу решить эту проблему, никто не мог мне помочь.
У меня проблема с прокруткой, я исползую angular/material в моем проекте и у меня есть mat-checkbox элементи. Когда mat-checkbox элемент checked прокрутка страницы блокируется, побробовал все что мог эфект 0. Ни какие ошибки при этом нет. Побробовал следить за собитием scroll вот таким функциам:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
      console.log('Scrolling-passive event');
    }, {
      capture: true,
      passive: true
    });

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      console.log('Scrolling');
    }, true);
```

когда прокрутка работает обе функци печатают в консоле, но когда прокрутка взломается в консоле печатается только "Scroll-passive event". В консоле смотрел Event Listeners  на этом элементе и не нашел никакие другие собитие, еще смотрел и css стили и тоже ноль эфект. И еще у меня в консоле включена Verbose и от него тоже нет такие сообщение о нарушение как это

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive
```

Помогите пожолуйста, уже не знаю что зделать.

Comment: Ничего не понятно из вопроса. Непонятно даже то, нужно запретить прокрутку, или исправить то, что её кто-то запретил.

Comment: Вопрос не правильно написал и сейчась не могу редактировать, Вопрос такой:
Прокрутка страницы блокируется, когда mat-checkbox элемент нажата, и нужно узнать от чего это происходит

Comment: @K-sS-k дружище, создай _минимальный воспроизводимый пример_ на stackblitz или codesandbox,  в этом случае 100% людям твой вопрос будет понятен

Comment: @overthesanity мой проект Angular 7 я использую в месте с Laravel, и некоторое часть фронта написан на AngularJs, и не могу создать этот минимал, мне придется вес проект перенести на stackblitz, а это будеть очень долго

Comment: Без примера вам никто не сможет помочь, к  сожалению.

Comment: А может кто нибудь сказать от чего может быть блокировка прокрутки?